# Word and printing certain items

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I'm trying to create a form to send to my candidates which will later be printed.  I created this form with word 2016 and for every field I want filled in I inserted a "Rich Text Content Control"

When I print a blank form, I get all these "Click or tap here to enter text" fields appearing on the print.

Is it possible to ONLY print these boxes when they are filled in by the candidate?

Comment: A screenshot might help convey your problem statement clearer. Could you post one of the form in question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, the message "Click or tap here to enter text" you get is the default text to guide users to type in text when your insert the Rich Text Content Control. It will appear when you print the document. There is no box border at all for two kinds of text content controls:Rich Text Content Control and Plain Text Content Control.

If you want to print the box border of a text contorl, I recomend that you use Text Box (ActiveX Control) instead.

For more information, read [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b)